# how to use api-platform serialization in custom symfony code

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a standard symonfy(6) app and api-platform(3) configured for some vue apps that are embedded on specific pages of my symfony app.

I want to use the json-ld serialization used by api-platform in non api code.

I can use the symfony serializer, and this works:

```
$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], ['json' => new JsonEncoder()]);


$output = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json', ['groups' => 'read'])
```

but that lacks some useful features, like the iri's of relatet entities ..
i would like to have the same serialization output, that apiPlatform generates.

How can i call the serializer to get exact the same result as i get from a configured url/endpoint?

Why do i want this: i have an vue app that needs to collect data from many endpoints for initialization. i want to prepare and give that data via the symfony-template that holds the entrypoint for the vue app.

Update:
I figured out a partial solution after some debugging the normal api process, but i'm sure i didnt see all consequences. you can use the api-platform serializer service in your services.
I build a wrapper service around the api-platform serializer, so i can autowire it in my controller:

```
    App\Utils\Api\OfflineApi:
        arguments: ['@api_platform.serializer']
```

controller:

```
public function action(EntityClass $entity, OfflineApi $offlineApi): Response {
   $offlineApi->serialize($entity, ['groups' => 'read']),
```

Comment: Try `$output = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'jsonld', ['groups' => 'read'])`. JSON-LD format will include the IRIs of relations. No hydra documentation though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i try this i get an exception from the symfony serializer "NotEncodableValueException" : Serialization for the format "jsonld" is not supported.
Problem is, that i dont get the api-platform serializer, and the symfony one doesn't know json-ld. with the mentioned workaround(offlineapi service) i get the api-platform serializer, and there i get json-ld per default. i just hoped there is a way which feels a bit less hacky.